# What is TokenPipe class in the Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

There is a class [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v23.0/src/util/tokenpipe.h#L75) in the Bitcoin core called `TokenPipe`. I've tried to figure out what is does but couldn't find anything useful. The comment says:

> An interprocess or interthread pipe for sending tokens (one-byte
> values) over.

But don't understand it. What are tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment says: 1-byte values.

It's an abstraction for sending byte values from one process to another process, for inter-process communication.

What those bytes are or what they represent is up to the code using this class.

The point is that users of the class don't need to know how that communication happens, and, in fact, may differ from one platform/operating system to another.